# Extjs Combobox: forceSelection false on combobox not working

Tags: extjs, combobox, sencha-architect

I have created a combobox and attached a array to store. What i wanted is that use can select from the list OR can type custom text as well. I searched that can be achieved through forceSelection = false, i read the docs that and found out that forceSelection is by default false and as i'm using sencha architect so i can't explicitly set the config. So below is the config which i have done. But as soon as i press tab or enter the typed text in combobox no longer exist.

```
{
xtype: 'fieldcontainer',                                    
id: 'internetmessager',
autoDestroy: false,
layout: {
    align: 'stretch',
    type: 'hbox'
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'combobox',
        flex: 1,
        margin: '0 10 0 0',
        name: 'label',
        autoSelect: false,
        queryMode: 'local',
        store: [
            'Home',
            'Work',
            'Personal'
        ],
        typeAhead: true
    },
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        flex: 2,
        name: 'value',
        emptyText: 'IM'
    }
]
}
```

Thanks,
Ali Abbas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a bug in sencha Architect 2.2.2, that the default value of 'forceSelection' is true but docs says it's false. And architect don't provide you way to make 'forceSelection' false b/c it's build by assuming that 'forceSelection' property is false. That what i comeup with correct me if i'm wrong. The workaround which i did, used the 'Process Confg' in arhitect config panel. which add the **processLabel** function

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    id: 'internetmessager',
    autoDestroy: false,
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [
        me.processLabel({
            xtype: 'combobox',
            flex: 1,
            margin: '0 10 0 0',
            name: 'label',
            store: [
                'Home',
                'Work',
                'Personal'
            ],
            valueField: 'text'
        }),
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            flex: 2,
            name: 'value',
            emptyText: 'IM'
        }
    ]
}
```

And in **processLabel** function i made forceSelection property false explicitly.

```
 processLabel: function(config) {        
    config.forceSelection = false;
    return config;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[edit]
oh man... I'm sorry...
After I reread your question againg, I realized you're using Sencha Architect
[/edit]

I'm not sure, if I understood you correctly...
What I did:
Write into combobox or select a value from its store.
When leaving (blur-listener) the combobox, the actual value is set into textfield.
btw: itemId's would be nice to use (imho)

```
    items: [
{
    xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
    id: 'internetmessager',
    autoDestroy: false,
    layout: {
        align: 'stretch',
        type: 'hbox'
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'combobox',
            flex: 1,
            margin: '0 10 0 0',
            name: 'label',
            autoSelect: false,
            queryMode: 'local',
            store: [
                'Home',
                'Work',
                'Personal'
            ],
            typeAhead: true,
            listeners: {
                blur: function (combo) {
                    Ext.ComponentQuery.query('[name=value]')[0].setValue(combo.getValue());
                }
            }
        },
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            flex: 2,
            name: 'value',
            emptyText: 'IM'
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No i think i didn't explain the thing rightly. What i actually wanted is that user can type custom label that not present in the Store Array. Means user can able to type 'Office' in the combobox and that value persist after user tab to other fields. What actually happening is that when i type 'Office' in combobox and then press tab value in combobox becomes empty.